# show TWO table rows

Tags: jquery, toggle

I am trying to show/hide the next two rows of a table using jquery.  The code below currently shows the tr with class - quest_image, but not class quest_text.

```
<table id="my_table">
<tr>
    <td><img alt="Show/Hide" src="img.gif" class="ShowHide"></td>
    <td>text 1</td>
</tr>
<tr class="quest_image">
    <td colspan="2">hidden text 1</td>
</tr>
<tr class="quest_text">
    <td colspan="2">hidden text 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><img alt="Show/Hide" src="img.gif" class="ShowHide"></td>
    <td>text 2</td>
</tr>
<tr class="quest_image">
    <td colspan="2">hidden text 4</td>
</tr>
<tr class="quest_text">
    <td colspan="2">hidden text 2</td>
</tr>

</table>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// bind click event ONCE to the table
// not to every .ShowHide
$('#my_table').click(function(event){

    // find where the click originated from
    var trigger = event.target;

    // if it has a class of "ShowHide"
    // THEN toggle the next row
    if(trigger.className == 'ShowHide')
    {
        // toggle away
        $(trigger).closest('tr').next('.quest_text').toggle();
        $(trigger).closest('tr').next('.quest_image').toggle();
    }
});
</script>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7TzJL/

Why does one toggle work, but not the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`next()` returns the immediate next element if the selector matches. It doesn't select the closest element with matching selector. You need to use `nextAll()` and limit it to the first match.

Also, jQuery 1.7 has `.on()` so you can drop the convoluted class check and bind the event to the classes directly. Don't forget to wrap everything in a document.ready event.

```
$( function() {
    $('#my_table').on( 'click', '.ShowHide', function() {
        var $trigger = $( this );
        $trigger.closest( 'tr' ).nextAll('.quest_text:first').toggle();
        $trigger.closest( 'tr' ).nextAll('.quest_image:first').toggle();
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MaPaX/

Comment: thanks, perfect.  Still learning the syntax of jquery. Powerful, but not as intuitive as JS, PHP, HTML, etc.